# Facing issue with docker creation to send layer 2 packet from docker to outer world

Tags: docker

My requirement is to send scapy layer 2 packet from docker to outer world.
Docker will be installed in a host linux machine.

The problem is if I am using port mapping and --network host docker is starting and stopped within 3 seconds. Below is the command
sudo docker run -itd  -p 30022:22 -p 36901:6901 -p 35901:5901 --privileged --network host --name

The reason for port mapping is to run multiple container in single host with vnc and no vnc and ssh.
The reason for --network host is to replicate host machine's ethernet interfaces in docker container to send scapy layer 2 packet to outer world.

Host machine info :- 4.15.0-54-generic #58~16.04.1-Ubuntu x86_64 
container info :- 4.15.0-54-generic #58~16.04.1-Ubuntu x86_64

Comment: Why is the container stopping; what does it print on its log output?  If your goals are to run VNC and ssh daemons and also to directly interact with a network interface, a virtual machine will be a much better match for you; running interactive login services like this in Docker isn't entirely natural, and the networking layer isn't really cooperative with that kind of low-level operation.  (`-p` and `--net host` don't go together, for instance.)

Comment: Container is sopping due to vnc error coz I amusing -p and -net host both. Is there any way like bridge network by which I can map single interface of host machine to docker container.